# Jquery Click button then trigger a button on second page with the same Class or ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

In my Project, I have a `<button id="first" class="first"` and I have a button with the same name and id on next page.
I want to trigger it when button on first page is clicked. Any thoughts how to do that?

I tried storing the button class on windows.LocalStorage and get the data on next page to be clicked but it's not working when opened in new tab.

thanks in Advance! hope you can help me.

Comment: you can use socket for that.

Comment: _“but it's not working when opened in new tab.”_ - why not? `localStorage` is tied to a specific _origin_, only `sessionStorage` is tied to the specific tab itself.

Comment: whenever I try localstorage or sessionstorage, it doesn't trigger anything. but when loaded on the same page, it works.

Comment: Please share your code that works/doesn't work, it's likely there is a possible problem in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two buttons with the same `id` or any two DOM elements in the same documents with the same `id`. So the solution to your issue, is to have different `id`s for each button. And do something as follows:

```html
<button id="button1" @click="clickButton2()">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" @click="doSomething()">Button 2</button>
```

While I would still recommend both `@click` to call `doSomething`, if for some reason you want to delegate clicking to the second button, your code for `clickButton2()` would be:

```js
function clickButton2() {
  document.getElementById('button2').click();
}
```

Comment: they're not on the same page. I want to trigger the button on the next page when i click the button on the current page